# i want a array of queries in a single model function with pagination in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

```
     This is my model
```

I dont know it is correct or not. i have a view page with pagination. i have to show a field of count with new column. so i have to write array of queries in a single model funtion.please help. please tell how it correctly call in controller

Model

```
public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
              $query1= $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
               $this->db->from('jil_requirements');
               $this->db->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
               $this->db->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
               $this->db->get();  


                 $query2= $this->db->select('count(*)');
                 $this->db->from('jil_mrorfq');
                 $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid', 'left');
                 $this->db->get();
                 return array(
          'categories' => $query1,
            'count' => $query2,
                              );
       } public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
              $query1= $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
               $this->db->from('jil_requirements');
               $this->db->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
               $this->db->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
               $this->db->get();  


                 $query2= $this->db->select('count(*)');
                 $this->db->from('jil_mrorfq');
                 $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid', 'left');
                 $this->db->get();
                 return array(
          'categories' => $query1,
            'count' => $query2,
                              );
       }
```

Controller

```
public function managerequirement() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/sidebar');

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "moderator/Requirement/managerequirement";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->requirement_model->record_count();

        $config["per_page"] = 20;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = 'first';
        $config['last_link'] = 'last';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) :0;
        $query= $this->requirement_model->
                fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);

        $data['results'] = $query['categories'];
        $data['count'] = $query['count'];
        print_r($data['results']);
         print_r( $data['count']);


        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();


        $this->load->view('moderator/managerequirement', $data);

        $this->load->view('moderator/templates/footer');
    }
```

View

```
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Dashboard) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Requirement Management
            <small></small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="active">Requirements</li>
            <li class="active">View All Requirements</li>
        </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3 class="box-title">View all Requirements</h3>  <div style="float:right"><?php echo $links; ?>  </div> 
                    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- form start -->

                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">

                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <th class="sorting" width="5%">#</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="30%">Requirement Service</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="10%">Posted By</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="10%">Managed By</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="15%">Quantity</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" width="15%">Posted  On</th>

                                        <th class="sorting" width="15%">Status</th>


                                    </tr>

                                    <?php
                                    if (!empty($results)) {
                                        foreach ($results as $row) {
                                            ?><tr>  
                                                <td class=" "><?php echo $row->rqm_id; ?></td>  
                                                <td class=" ">   <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'moderator/Requirement/viewrequirementdetails/' . $row->rqm_id ?>"><?php echo $row->rqm_service; ?></a></td>
                                                <td class=" "><?php
                                    echo $row->usr_name;
                                            ?></td>  
                                                <td class=" "><?php
                                                    echo $row->mer_name;
                                                    ?></td>  
                                                <td class=" "><?php
                                                    echo $row->rqm_quantity;
                                                    ?></td>  
                                                <td class=" "><?php echo date('d-M-Y', $row->rqm_dated); ?></td>  
                                                <td class=" "><?php
                                                    if ($row->rqm_permission == '0') {
                                                        echo "In-Active";
                                                    } else if ($row->rqm_permission == '1') {
                                                        echo "Active";
                                                    } else if ($row->rqm_permission == '2') {
                                                        echo "Pending";
                                                    } else if ($row->rqm_permission == '3') {
                                                        echo "Suspend";
                                                    } else if ($row->rqm_permission == '4') {
                                                        echo "Delete";
                                                    }
                                                    ?></td>  
                                            </tr>  
                                                <?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>  

                                </table>

                                            <?php echo $links; ?>   
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-xs-6">

                            </div> 
                        </div>




                    </diV>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->


            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Comment: when i print_r i got a result like this                                                                    Object ( [dbdriver] => mysql [compress] => [delete_hack] => 1 [stricton] => [_escape_char:protected] => ` [return_delete_sql:protected] => [reset_delete_data:protected] => [qb_select:protected] => Array ( )  like something

Comment: add the coding like this  $query1 =  $this->db->get();

Comment: ok. i want to correct the second query.can u help?

Comment: i have a table "requirement"  and another table "mrorfq" i have find out the count of each requirement id from "requirement" in "mrorfq". pls help

Comment: use num_rows() in second query and remove count(*) in select() add any one field

Comment: can i use group by. i have to find the count of each requirement id

Comment: are you want record count in jil_mrorfq table ? I don't structure of your table.

Comment: yes   $this->db->select('count(*)');
             $this->db->from('jil_mrorfq');
             $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid', 'left');
             $this->db->group_by('jil_requirements.rqm_id'); 
             $query2= $this->db->get();
             
              if ($query2->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query2->result() as $row) {
                 $data2[] = $row;
            }
              } is this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101366/discussion-between-vaira-muthu-and-angel).

Answer (score 0):

Try this coding

```
 public function fetch_data($limit, $start) {
               $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
               $this->db->from('jil_requirements');
               $this->db->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
               $this->db->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
              $get_query1 = $this->db->get();  
             $query1 = $get_query1->result();



                $this->db->select('rfq_requirementid');
                 $this->db->from('jil_mrorfq');
                 $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid', 'left');
                 $get_query2 =  $this->db->get();
              $field_count = $get_query2->num_rows();

                 return array(
          'categories' => $query1,
            'count' =>$field_count
                   );
       }
```

Comment: how count can be access in view page?

Comment: $data['count'] = $query['count']; in controller and access the $count variable in view file

Comment: thats in controller. how it echo in view page?

Comment: <?php echo $count; ?>

Comment: that is in a foreach loop na?

Comment: any place in view file, not only foreach loop

Comment: glap help to you. can you accept and upvote my answer ?

Comment: its a table of data with data of each requirement. so a number of counts to be shown. how it get in a single $count?

Comment: how foreach  this array   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count(*)] => 35 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [count(*)] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( tdClass Object ( [count(*)] =>

Comment: see my controller. i passed arraay $data to view page. how foreach $count array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101380/discussion-between-vaira-muthu-and-angel).